# Does for loop count elements added into itself during the loop?

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

My question is, that when I loop through a list with for loop, and add elements to it during this, does it count the elements added while looping?
Simple code example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfIds.Count(); i++) // Does loop counts the items added below?
{
    foreach (var post in this.Collection)
    {
        if (post.ResponsePostID == listOfIds.ElementAt(i))
        {
            listOfIds.Add(post.PostId); // I add new item to list in here
        }
    }
}
```

I hope my explanation is good enough for you to understand what my question is.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it usually does. But changing a collection at the same time you're iterating over it can lead to weird behavior and hard-to-find bugs. It isn't recommended at all.

Comment: Allright, thanks. But, do you have any suggestions how to do it in recommended way? 
Basically what i want to do is to get the count of all elementis in a tree look-a-like structure. That was the easiest way what i found.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this loop run only for preAdded item count then do this

```
int nLstCount =  listOfIds.Count();
for (int i = 0; i < nLstCount ; i++) 
{
foreach (var post in this.Collection)
{
    if (post.ResponsePostID == listOfIds.ElementAt(i))
    {
        listOfIds.Add(post.PostId);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Nope, i want to loop thru all items, including these what i add during the loop.

Comment: This is not recommended as suggest by Dennis. It can cause serious issues in your logic

Answer (score 0):

Yes it surely will.The inner foreach loop will execute and add the elements the outer collection and thus will increament the count of the elements.

listOfIds.Count=2 //iteration 1

listOfIds.Add(//element)

when it come to the for loop again

listOfIds.Count=3 //iteration 2

Answer (score 0):

As a slightly abridged explanation of the `for` loop. You're essentially defining the following:

```
for (initializer; condition; iterator)
body
```

Your `initializer` will will establish your initial conditions, and will only happen once (effectively outside the loop).

Your `condition` will be evaluated **every time** to determine whether your loop should run again, or simply exit.

Your `iterator` defines an action that will occur after each iteration in your loop.

So in your case, your loop will reevaluate `listOfIds.Count();` each time, to decide if it should execute; that may or may not be your desired behaviour.

As Dennis points out, you can let yourself get into a bit of a mess (youy loop may run infinitely) if you aren't careful.

A much more detailed/better written explanation can be found on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx